# Sidebar panel vscode extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

How do I create a sidebar?

I have figured out that `registerWebviewViewProvider` can help but what the provider is and how I create one.

In javascript

**EDIT**

You can see these files

https://github.com/AryaAnish121/vs-flow-extension/blob/master/package.json
https://github.com/AryaAnish121/vs-flow-extension/blob/master/src/extension.js

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/webview-view-sample

Comment: Thanks but how do I do it in javascript

Comment: Compile the `.ts` file? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Thanks but I asked for who files in javascript. But thanks